# What is the difference between zig-zag of Splay tree and rotation of AVL tree?

Tags: algorithm, tree

I am learning Splay tree right now and get confused about zig-zag. What is the difference between it and left and right rotation in AVL tree?

Answer (score 2):

A Zig-zag rotation is exactly the same as an AVL double rotation.

In AVL tree's we have double rotations: A right rotation and a left rotation OR a left rotation and a right rotation.

A Zig-Zag rotation is the same as that.

Comment: An Answer requires bit more details.